# I'm having an issue making a react component play an mp3 file when a button is clicked, it looks like it should work to me but something is wrong

Tags: reactjs, mp3

I'm trying to make the buttons here each play the mp3 file they correspond to. The buttons wont
play the mp3 files and I'm not getting any errors I'm aware of. The files are located directly
in the src folder. I had the files in the public folder as was recommended by another stack overflow post but having them in the src folder seemed to work, then when i added the rest of the buttons the whole thing stopped working, so you see I'm stuck. Should i put the functions directly in the onClick? What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
    function App() {
      
     let workIt = new Audio('/workit.mp3');
     let doIt = new Audio('/doit.mp3');
     let harder = new Audio('/harder.mp3');
     let faster = new Audio('/faster.mp3');
     let moreThan = new Audio('/morethan.mp3');
     let our = new Audio('/our.mp3');
     let ever = new Audio('/ever.mp3');
     let workIs = new Audio('/workis.mp3');
     let makeIt = new Audio('/makeit.mp3');
     let makesUs = new Audio('/makesus.mp3');
     let better = new Audio('/better.mp3');
     let stronger = new Audio('/stronger.mp3');
     let hour = new Audio('/hour.mp3');
     let never = new Audio('/never.mp3');
     let after = new Audio('/after.mp3');
     let over = new Audio('/over.mp3');
    
      const playWorkIt = () => {
        workIt.play()
      }
      const playDoIt = () => {
        doIt.play();
      }
      const playHarder = () => {
        harder.play();
      }
      const playFaster = () => {
        faster.play()
      }
      const playMoreThan = () => {
        moreThan.play()
      }
      const playOur = () => {
        our.play()
      }
      const playEver = () => {
        ever.play()
      }
      const playWorkIs = () => {
        workIs.play()
      }
      const playMakeIt = () => {
        makeIt.play()
      }
      const playMakesUs = () => {
        makesUs.play()
      }
      const playBetter = () => {
        better.play()
      }
      const playStronger = () => {
        stronger.play()
      }
      const playHour = () => {
        hour.play()
      }
      const playNever = () => {
        never.play()
      }
      const playAfter = () => {
        after.play()
      }
      const playOver = () => {
        over.play()
      }
    
      return (
        <div className = 'app'>
          <div className = 'left'>
            <button onClick = {playWorkIt} className = 'work-it'>Work it</button>
            <button onClick = {playDoIt} className = 'do-it'>Do it</button>
            <button onClick = {playHarder} className = 'harder'>Harder</button>
            <button onClick = {playFaster} className = 'faster'>Faster</button>
            <button onClick = {playMoreThan} className = 'more-than'>More Than</button>
            <button onClick = {playOur} className = 'our'>Our</button>
            <button onClick = {playEver} className = 'ever'>Ever</button>
            <button onClick = {playWorkIs} className = 'work-is'>Work is</button>
          </div>
          <div className = 'right'>
            <button onClick = {playMakeIt} className = 'make-it'>Make it</button>
            <button onClick = {playMakesUs} className = 'makes-us'>Makes us</button>
            <button onClick = {playBetter} className = 'better'>Better</button>
            <button onClick = {playStronger} className = 'stronger'>Stronger</button>
            <button onClick = {playHour} className = 'hour'>Hour</button>
            <button onClick = {playNever} className = 'never'>Never</button>
            <button onClick = {playAfter} className = 'after'>After</button>
            <button onClick = {playOver} className = 'over'>Over</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i did need it in the public folder my bad, sorry for the premature question